# can I map multiple presses of <any key>?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement

I want to make more use of `fF` to navigate, but find the `f` to be clumsy. Eg. jump to "a" is `fa`.

Instead, I'd like `aaa` to map to `fa`, `bbb`to map to `fb` etc.

Is there an easy way to do this other than lots of `:nmap aaa fa`?
I'm all in on Neovim, so lua solutions are ok.

Alternative approaches also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a loop:

```
for c in range(97, 122)
  for offset in [0, 32]
    let key = nr2char(c - offset)
    execute "nnoremap " .. repeat(key, 3) .. " f" .. key
  endfor
endfor
```

Personally, I would find this unusable, though, as now every normal-mode command you issue will have a delay while Vim waits for your `'timeout'` to see whether you're typing your mapping.

On the up side, it would force you to use motions properly as you can no longer spam motions repeatedly to get places!

Comment: thx. That worked well. I didn't find the timeout to be an issue.
Unfortunately, the issue I did find was that folke/which-key.nvim got confused by my intentions.
I've reverted to "<space><space> f" & "<space><space><space> ;"

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
for c in ['a', 'b' ......]
    exe "noremap " . repeat(c, 3) . " f".c
endfor
```

But honestly I wouldn't do that because you will hide all other legit keybindings.

- `aaa` is append "aa"
- `bbb` is back, back, back
- `ccc` is change line with "c"
- `ddd` is delete line, and prepare to delete something else
- and so on.

Even if you think you won't need "append aa", the first "a" still says: "I'm changing the current mode with append", etc.